# Research for misbehavior detection in WiFI networks

Tags: neural-networks, research

I'm looking for research which discusses misbehavior detection in public internet access networks using ANN approaches.

So it can be used by [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) to detect suspicious users connected to their network.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One popular technique for doing this is to use [Artificial Immune Systems](http://www.artificial-immune-systems.org/), an evolutionary computation approach which maintains a population of pattern detectors.

Here is a [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.1266.pdf).